# scraping reviews from playstore using google_play_scraper

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, google-play-services

I am trying to scrap the reviews for an app using google_play_scraper, the play store says 16thousand reviews but I am only able to scrap 4869 reviews. what could be the reason?

As you can see I am trying to use all the languages available via a function.

I am using the below code

```
# Import necessary libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from google_play_scraper import app, Sort, reviews_all

# Define function to scrape reviews for a specific country and language combination
def scrape_reviews(country, lang):
    reviews = reviews_all(
        'com.canda.mobileapp',
        sleep_milliseconds=0,
        lang=lang,
        country=country,
        sort=Sort.NEWEST
    )
    reviews_df = pd.DataFrame(reviews)
    try:
        reviews_df = reviews_df[['reviewId', 'userName', 'userImage', 'content', 'score', 'thumbsUpCount', 'reviewCreatedVersion', 'at', 'replyContent', 'repliedAt']].assign(Country_name=df.loc[df['country'] == country, 'Country_name'].iloc[0], Language=lang)
    except KeyError:
        reviews_df = pd.DataFrame()
    return reviews_df

# Define dataframe containing country and language combinations
data = {'Country_name': ['Belgium', 'Belgium', 'Belgium', 'Belgium', 'Czechia', 'Czechia', 'Denmark', 'Denmark', 'Germany', 'Germany', 'Greece', 'Greece', 'Spain', 'Spain', 'France', 'France', 'Croatia', 'Croatia', 'Italy', 'Italy', 'Hungary', 'Hungary', 'Netherlands', 'Netherlands', 'Austria', 'Austria', 'Poland', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Portugal', 'Romania', 'Romania', 'Switzerland', 'Switzerland', 'Switzerland', 'Switzerland', 'Switzerland', 'Slovakia', 'Slovakia', 'Slovenia', 'Slovenia', 'Sweden', 'Sweden', 'Finland', 'Finland'],
        'country': ['BE', 'BE', 'BE', 'BE', 'CZ', 'CZ', 'DK', 'DK', 'DE', 'DE', 'GR', 'GR', 'ES', 'ES', 'FR', 'FR', 'HR', 'HR', 'IT', 'IT', 'HU', 'HU', 'NL', 'NL', 'AT', 'AT', 'PL', 'PL', 'PT', 'PT', 'RO', 'RO', 'CH', 'CH', 'CH', 'CH', 'CH', 'SK', 'SK', 'SI', 'SI', 'SE', 'SE', 'FI', 'FI'],
        'Language': ['Dutch', 'French', 'German', 'English', 'Czech', 'English', 'Danish', 'English', 'German', 'English', 'Greek', 'English', 'Spanish', 'English', 'French', 'English', 'Croatian', 'English', 'Italian', 'English', 'Hungarian', 'English', 'Dutch', 'English', 'German', 'English', 'Polish', 'English', 'Portuguese', 'English', 'Romanian', 'English', 'German', 'French', 'Italian', 'Romansh', 'English', 'Slovak', 'English', 'Slovenian', 'English', 'Swedish', 'English', 'Finnish', 'English'],
        'lang': ['nl', 'fr', 'de', 'en', 'cs', 'en', 'da', 'en', 'de', 'en', 'el', 'en', 'es', 'en', 'fr', 'en', 'hr', 'en', 'it', 'en', 'hu', 'en', 'nl', 'en', 'de', 'en', 'pl', 'en', 'pt', 'en', 'ro', 'en', 'de', 'fr', 'it', 'rm', 'en', 'sk', 'en', 'sl', 'en', 'sv', 'en', 'fi', 'en']
       }


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

reviews_dfs = df.apply(lambda row: scrape_reviews(row['country'], row['lang']), axis=1)
combined_reviews_df = pd.concat(reviews_dfs.to_list(), ignore_index=True)

#remove duplicates
combined_reviews_df = combined_reviews_df.groupby(['content', 'Language']).first().reset_index()
combined_reviews_df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that out of these 16k reviews only 4869 contains "review" and other 11k are just ratings without any comment.

To verify the quantity of "reviews", you could check and call a [Google Play Product](https://www.searchapi.io/docs/google-play-product) SearchAPI, in which you could get all selected product reviews.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to do with ISO standards in certain countries?

Quoting from the relevant [PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/google-play-scraper/):

> The country and language codes that can be included in the lang and country parameters described below depend on the [ISO 3166](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes) and [ISO 639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) standards, respectively. Therefore, we recommend using an ISO database library such as [pycountry](https://github.com/flyingcircusio/pycountry).